# AJAX button processes, doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've found a lot of people with the same problem I have, but none of the solutions apply to my situation. I am following [Michael Hartl's tutorial here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax). I have a follow system set up in accordance with chapter 14 (I'm using the latest edition of the book, as I am on Rails 5.1). The follow/unfollow button processes in the database, but I have to manually refresh the page to see the button and follow count change.

I get this in the browser console log:

```
POST  500 (Internal Server Error)
    jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:10255 
    send @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:10255
    ajax @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:9739
    ajax @ jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js:94
    handleRemote @ jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js:179
    (anonymous) @ jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js:512
    dispatch @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:5227
    elemData.handle @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:4879
```

relationships_controller.rb:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
      format.js 
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

views/users/_follow.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

views/users/_unfollow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id),
                   html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

views/users/_follow_form.html.erb

```
<% if current_user != @user %>
  <div id="follow_form">
    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
      <%= render 'unfollow' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'follow' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

relationships/create.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

relationships/destroy.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy,
                                        :following, :followers]

  def index
    @page_title = "Forge Users"
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers
    render 'show_follow'
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it should change the button? Where is the `onclick()` Javascript event? What does `:back` go to in this? `redirect_to(:back)` Try to `redirect_to user_path(@user)` or whatever page it is you are looking at, then it will reload the page. Why do you say AJAX in your title, but there are no AJAX calls (`$.post()`) in your question? Show the JS for that.

Comment: did you include jquery_ujs?

Comment: I have jquery_ujs required in my application.js file.

Comment: Chloe, when the form is processed, the relationship controller should be doing all the js stuff (calling upon create.js and destroy.js). Am I wrong?

Comment: Is it giving any server errors in the Network tab of your browser's debugging console? What about any errors in the Console tab? Don't you need a `render` in the `format.js`?

Comment: No errors in the console, it is saying everything is rendered properly. The render of the js happens in the create.js and destroy.js. I've updated my question to show the link to the tutorial itself.

Comment: OK now show us the log in `log\development.log` when you click the button. `POST  500 (Internal Server Error)` means a server side error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set local variable `user`

```
def create
  user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
```

but reference class instance variable `@user` in your `.js.erb` template.

```
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

Instead, set `@user = User.find(params[:followed_id])` so it is available to the views. Actually, I think you are trying to set `@user = current_user`. That might make more sense.

Comment: Change it to @user = ... actually broke the entire functionality so that the db part doesn't even work.

Comment: The problem was that all the variables in the method needed to be instance variables.

Answer (score -1):

You need to rename your Javascript files to have `.erb` ending.

`relationships/create.js.erb` and `relationships/destroy.js.erb`. It's because you have Ruby in the file so it has to process the Ruby before it gets interpreted as Javascript and sent back.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example

Comment: my mistake, they have the .js.erb extension in my app, I messed it up on here.

Comment: Can you add `console.log("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");` to them and see if it renders the correct text in the browser console?

Comment: I added the console stuff to my question.